# How do I use the .random.choice() function with urls (specifically gifs)?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I recently created a pretty simple discord bot that on command, will give you a random quote from the options. I want to do the same, but with gifs. Is the formatting the same?

The first code is my quote bot coding, the second is my attempt at embedding a gif, but I'm not sure how to incorporate .random.choice() into this...

```
@client.command(brief='-positivity', description='will give you a positive quote!')
async def positivity(ctx):
    quotes = [#choice1, #choice2, ...., choice#25]
    await ctx.send(f'**{random.choice(quotes)}**')

\\

@client.command(brief='-hug', desription="Will give you a warm hug")
async def hug(ctx):
    gif = discord.Embed(title = 'A hug has been sent!', description = 'warm, fuzzy and comforting <3', color = 0x83B5E3)
    gif.set_image(url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/fvN5KrNcKKUyX7hNIA/giphy.gif')
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=gif)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'gif2'
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'gif2'
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'gif1'
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'url3'
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'gif1'
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'url3'
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'gif2'
>>> random.choice(['gif1', 'gif2', 'url3', 'hello world'])
'hello world'
```

Which I guess you might want to do something like this with:

```
quotes = ['quote one', 'etc...']
await ctx.send(random.choice(quotes))
```

Comment: do i need to add url='URL' or do i just put: ['url1', 'url2', etc]?